# What kind of paper to use for airbrush practice?

Tags: paper, medium-selection, airbrush

I'm just getting started with an airbrush and I plan to spend some time practicing basic techniques (dots, straight lines, curves, etc.) using cheap acrylic paints which I will dilute down to airbrush paint consistency.

I eventually plan to use my (yet to be developed) airbrush skills on smooth non-porous surfaces like metal and hard plastic.   At that time, I will move up to real airbrush paints, but I hope to have developed comfortable control of the brush before then.

**Question: What cheap paper types are appropriate for beginner-level airbrush practice?**

I'm assuming that "low-absorption" and "extremely smooth" are traits which I should be looking for, but beyond that, I don't have a clue.

Also, if there are non-paper mediums that would serve better, (I am currently using those red-plastic disposable plates)... please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper you are looking for is "Bond" which has a smooth plate surface.

You could also use Hard Press or Hot Press water color paper but that will be more absorbent.

Comment: Thanks!  That information will help a lot!  +1 I was getting tired of showing off my painted plastic plates to my friends.

Comment: There are bond papers specifically made for airbrushing out there too, but any bond should do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new in the hobby and newer with my airbrush, sometimes I use plastic bottles and aluminium cans. I try draw to draw the patterns.

Comment: i know its no paper but i want share what i do ;)

Comment: Ever try paper cups?

Comment: Thanks for the idea!   There seems to be something wrong with the points buttons.  I've tried to give you a +1, but the counter only goes negative.  Never seen it do that before.  Thanks!